# Using standard read() and write() calls on a socket in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

Is there anything bad with using `read()` and `write()` on a socket fd, instead of `send()` and `recv()`? I thought about using that in my program because `read()` and `write()` are much simpler than `send()` and `recv()`.

Comment: Not having a single extra parameter that you set to zero makes them "much simpler"?!

Answer (score 3):

No, there's nothing wrong with it, `man 7 socket` tells you explicitly that you can use the standard calls on them.

Though the send and recv functions aren't really hard to use, you can just pass 0 as the flags argument to get the same behavior as plain read and write.